# Modal will only display if not hidden by default

Tags: javascript, php, html, woocommerce

I was recently asked to add a modal to a WooCommerce product page when the 'add to cart' button is pressed. As a start, I copied and modified the w3schools modal example and inserted it into my child theme's single-product > add-to-cart > simple.php file. When I comment out the CSS line that hides the modal by default, clicking the button brings up the modal, just like it does in the example. When I leave that line enabled, however, the modal will not display when the button is pressed. I have tried using opacity instead of the display property, but achieved no meaningfully different results. I have some experience with reasonably basic HTML and almost none with PHP, but my best guess as to what's happening is that this is some form of order-of-execution issue.

Here is the demonstration code from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the relevant portion of my simple.php file:

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

global $product;

if ( ! $product->is_purchasable() ) {
    return;
}

echo wc_get_stock_html( $product ); // WPCS: XSS ok.

if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>



                                                    <!-- Add code for modal here -->
                        <!-- Some style stuff -->

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>SAMPLE TEXT HERE</p>
  </div>

</div>

<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    /*display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 500px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #ff0080;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>


    <form class="cart" action="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', $product->get_permalink() ) ); ?>" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

        <?php
         do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity' );

         /*woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
            'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
            'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
            'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( wp_unslash( $_POST['quantity'] ) ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), // WPCS: CSRF ok, input var ok.
        ) ); */

        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity' ); 
        ?>      

        <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>




<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("single_add_to_cart_button button alt");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
modal.style.display = "none";
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>



        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
    </form>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I have tried moving the HTML and CSS portions to other files, but this has not fixed the issue. Most of what I have been able to find via internet research simply suggests that I set `.modal {display: none;}` by default, which is what the example is already doing. Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: `var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("single_add_to_cart_button button alt");` and then `btn.onclick = function() {...}`. You can't attach events to NodeList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button is being caught, and the modal is getting ready to do its thing. However, the form is then submitted, and the browser does its thing - navigates away from the page. I've modified your code a bit, so now it captures - and then prevents - the form from being submitted.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the form
var form = document.getElementById('myForm');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementById('myModalClose');


// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
form.onsubmit = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    return false;
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 500px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #ff0080;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <span id="myModalClose" class="close">&times;</span>
  <p>SAMPLE TEXT HERE</p>
 </div>
</div>

<form id="myForm" class="cart" action="#" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">my button</button>
</form>
```